# WPF image over video flicker

Tags: wpf, rendering, kinect

I have found a lot of similar posts about this, but none that are recent or actually address the issue. Hoping someone can help. Sorry if this is duplicate. I am not a WPF or xaml expert and have cobbled together code from various sources.

Scenario:-

- Kiosk style app not for production, just for an exhibition
- WPF app playing video as background on a grid using a mediaplayer being drawn with a brush
- Kinect sensor to determine position of a person with state change events to change the source of the video based on the person's orientation (out of range, in range and looking at the sensor)
- 3 Image controls (with PNG images with transparency as the source) over the top of the video which represent the persons current state. Images are collapsed or visible depending on the state

Everything is working as I am expecting it to, but there is a flicker (either solid white or black background) on the Image control when the Visibility of the images change when over the top of the video. If I hide the video as a test, there is no flicker, which suggests to me a rendering/drawing problem with the layering of the images and video. I started by borrowing from the Microsoft Kinect V2 samples and then building from there, but I don't think the Kinect itself would be causing the issue. All of the PC's I have been testing on exhibit this behaviour and are all recent powerful machines that have no problem running more complex applications.

Basic Video setup code (because I read about it somewhere, I didn't come up with it myself)

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
mp.MediaEnded += MediaElement_MediaEnded;
mp.MediaOpened += MediaElement_MediaOpened;
VideoDrawing vd = new VideoDrawing();
vd.Player = mp;
vd.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
DrawingBrush db = new DrawingBrush(vd);
grid.Background = db;
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="IgnoreYou.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Kinect 2 Face HD (.NET)"
    Height="735" Width="770" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closed="Window_Closing"
    WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Topmost="True"
    MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">

<Grid Name="grid">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <WrapPanel Margin="0,0,0,30">
            <Image Name="noPerson" Source="images/noone.png" Stretch="None" >
            </Image>
            <Image Name="seenPerson" Source="images/can_you_see.png" Stretch="None" Visibility="Collapsed" >
            </Image>
            <Image Name="ignorePerson" Source="images/ignored.png" Stretch="None" Visibility="Collapsed" >
            </Image>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Switching the images example code (there are 3 variations):-

```
noPerson.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
ignorePerson.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
seenPerson.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I've looked various things
 - Setting cachemode on images
 - Doublebuffering doesn't seem to be thing anymore with modern WPF apps?
 - Using opacity instead of visibility
 - Stopping the video before the visibility is set (although probably doesn't matter without an actual delay timer?)
 - Although the Kinect is firing at 30fps, the "person state change" events are only fired once and the switching code only fires once i.e. there are flags set to stop repeat entries

It doesn't do it all of the time, just most of the time.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Jarrod

Comment: Putting the video into a control's background seems a little unconventional! See if you can find a way to put the video into an <Image> control instead, and place that behind your <StackPanel> of buttons. Failing that, keep things more or less how they are but have the <StackPanel> on top of the <Grid> rather than as a child. See if either of these helps the flickering.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't remember the exact reason for using the media player, except that I was having issues when I used a media element, maybe because of the way that I switching the videos in and out or something to do with positioning and scaling. A post I read suggested that method and it worked well for me, except for the flickering (which was a last second change to add the images). Will try your suggestion. Found out that the images are clipping through to the app background and a temporary solution I am using is to put a still of the video in the background so it clips to that.

Comment: I remember now why I didn't use media element. There is a horrible flickering when switching videos. The suggestion I read regarding using mediaplayer I think was about performance differences. I also tried to move the Image overlays so they weren't in the same layer as the background but unfortunately it still clipped. @AndrewStephens you mentioned putting Video into and Image control, but I didn't understand what you meant? It is an mp4 video, but the Image source didn't like that?

Comment: I was probably being a bit specific with the Image thing, sorry. What I was really trying to say was that you should try embedding the video in a control of its own, *behind* the button StackPanel. It was to test the theory that the flickering might be due to the video being used as the Grid's background. Perhaps redrawing this custom background and the children (StackPanel, Buttons) requires more resources than if the video was simply behind them all.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a real answer, but the problem was that the background behind the video was clipping through in the space that the image took up. I couldn't find a way of making the rendering more stable.

The video I was using was relatively static i.e. it was a very short loop, so I took a still frame of the video and made that the background. You could still see it flick between the video and the still at that point (if you knew what you were looking for), but the difference was negligible in my case - it was also much better than a solid white block appearing for a split second.

Comment: Thanks!  This issue has plagued me for a couple of years now, and I've never been able to find a decent answer as to how to fix it or what was happening - I wish there was a better solution (e.g. old school double-buffering for example, but I don't think this is how WPF rendering works).  Non the less, I'm going to give your suggestion a try, as I have a similar scenario - short repeating video loop.  I'll snap a still and put it as the background.   Thanks a mil!

Comment: Glad I could help someone 2 years later.

I was a bit surprised that in this day and age of modern computing, something like this would be an issue. I fought with it for a while, but the solution ended up going with stood up to the test. Only needed to make it run for a couple of weeks anyway so c'est la vie.